# codeigniter not working on godaddy windows hosting (plesk)

Tags: php, codeigniter, plesk, windows-hosting

My codeigniter project is working fine on local xamp, but when i hosted it on godaddy window hosting (plesk) it always loading the default controller. 
below is my config file:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'my_site_url';
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
```

and web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Rewrite to index.php">
                    <match url="index.php|robots.txt|images|test.php" />
                    <action type="None" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="Rewrite CI Index">
                    <match url=".*" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" pattern="css|js|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|htm|html" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php/{R:0}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: See: https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/wiki/Godaddy-Installation-Tips

Comment: First of all test your project with index.php. Check here is this working mode or not . If issue remain same then take next step for remove index.php from url

Comment: Got it, Thanks both

Comment: @Waffles Has anyone solved this? If so then how? Does the above github instruction works on godaddy plesk?